# Underset spacing

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I've got the following equation

```
\begin{align*}
  \hat{\boldsymbol{\eta}} = \underset{(\boldsymbol{\beta}_{1}, \ldots,
  \boldsymbol{\beta}_{d}, \boldsymbol{\theta}) \in B_{1} \times
  \cdots \times B_{d} \times \Theta}{\text{arg max }}
  \ell(\boldsymbol{\beta}_{1}, \ldots, \boldsymbol{\beta}_{d}, \boldsymbol{\theta})
\end{align*}
```

resulting in

[image: Problematic spacing]

I would like for the expression under "arg max" to be positioned a bit lower so that the large horizontal spaces disappear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the example below, the first equation reproduces what you have right now, while the second equation achieves your stated objective (by encasing the subscript material in a `\mathclap` directive). Note the use of `\strut` to force a bit more whitespace between the two lines. Even so, the reader may have to study the equation for more time than should be required to figure out what the material in the second line pertains to.

The third equation below uses the `\substack` macro to insert a judiciously-chosen line break in the subscript material. IMNSHO, breaking up the subscript material into two parts strikes a reasonable balance between compact appearance and readability of the equation.

Note that the code also defines a dedicated "math operator" named `\argmax`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,bm}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max} 

\begin{document}
\[
  \hat{\bm{\eta}} = \argmax_{(\bm{\beta}_{1}, \dots,
  \bm{\beta}_{d}, \bm{\theta}) \in B_{1} \times
  \cdots \times B_{d} \times \Theta}
  \ell(\bm{\beta}_{1}, \dots, \bm{\beta}_{d}, \bm{\theta})
\]

\bigskip
\[
  \hat{\bm{\eta}} = \argmax_{\strut\mathclap{(\bm{\beta}_{1}, \dots,
  \bm{\beta}_{d}, \bm{\theta}) \in B_{1} \times
  \cdots \times B_{d} \times \Theta}}
  \ell(\bm{\beta}_{1}, \dots, \bm{\beta}_{d}, \bm{\theta})
\]

\bigskip
\[
  \hat{\bm{\eta}} = \argmax_{\substack{(\bm{\beta}_{1}, \dots,
  \bm{\beta}_{d}, \bm{\theta}) \in \\ (B_{1} \times
  \cdots \times B_{d} \times \Theta)}}
  \ell(\bm{\beta}_{1}, \dots, \bm{\beta}_{d}, \bm{\theta})
\]

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: The `\substack` and `\mathclap` approaches may be combined, to create the following look:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,bm}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}

\begin{document}

\[
  \hat{\bm{\eta}} = \argmax_{\mathclap{\substack{
     (\bm{\beta}_{1}, \dots,\bm{\beta}_{d}, \bm{\theta}) \in \\ 
     (B_{1} \times \cdots \times B_{d} \times \Theta)}}} \,
  \ell(\bm{\beta}_{1}, \dots, \bm{\beta}_{d}, \bm{\theta})
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I like the third one (the line break makes it more readable). Is it possible to reduce the horizontal space?

Comment: @user2249626 - Sure, just encase the entire two-line subscript in a `\mathclap` directive. I'll post an addendum to show how to do this.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest an alternative notation:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \hat{\boldsymbol{\eta}} = \operatorname{arg\,max}\bigl\{
  \ell(\boldsymbol{\beta}_{1}, \ldots, \boldsymbol{\beta}_{d},
  \boldsymbol{\theta}) : (\boldsymbol{\beta}_{1}, \dots,
  \boldsymbol{\beta}_{d}, \boldsymbol{\theta}) \in B_{1} \times
  \cdots \times B_{d} \times \Theta \bigl\}
\end{equation*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Should that maybe be `\colon` instead of `:`?

Comment: @Mico I only use `\colon` when defining a function, in that case (I think) it's a normal `:` which is a relation, exactly the same as `\mid`.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways: `\mathclap` (requires `mathtools` package) or a `\stackunder` (requires `stackengine` package), which allows vertical underset distance to be set.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine,mathtools}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \hat{\boldsymbol{\eta}} = \underset{\mathclap{(\boldsymbol{\beta}_{1}, \ldots,
  \boldsymbol{\beta}_{d}, \boldsymbol{\theta}) \in B_{1} \times
  \cdots \times B_{d} \times \Theta}}{\text{arg max }}
  \ell(\boldsymbol{\beta}_{1}, \ldots, \boldsymbol{\beta}_{d}, \boldsymbol{\theta})
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}
  \hat{\boldsymbol{\eta}} = \stackunder[5pt]{\text{arg max }}{
  \scriptstyle(\boldsymbol{\beta}_{1}, \ldots,
  \boldsymbol{\beta}_{d}, \boldsymbol{\theta}) \in B_{1} \times
  \cdots \times B_{d} \times \Theta}
  \ell(\boldsymbol{\beta}_{1}, \ldots, \boldsymbol{\beta}_{d}, \boldsymbol{\theta})
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Third</strike> Fourth way: `\smashoperator` (requires `mathtools` package), which does the same as `\mathclap` in a sub and superscript, but also features an optional argument in case you only want to “clap” one side, e.g., `\smashoperator[r]{..}`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \hat{\boldsymbol{\eta}} = \smashoperator{\argmax_{(\boldsymbol{\beta}_{1}, \ldots,
  \boldsymbol{\beta}_{d}, \boldsymbol{\theta}) \in B_{1} \times
  \cdots \times B_{d} \times \Theta}}
  \ell(\boldsymbol{\beta}_{1}, \ldots, \boldsymbol{\beta}_{d}, \boldsymbol{\theta})
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

In any case I would add some space manually like `\quad \smashoperator{..} \quad`. Or even normal text rather than as a subscript.

Comment: Mico, is that edit what you mean? I think the spacing doesn't change, just  added a few words.

Comment: Indeed, the `\smashoperator[r]{...}` variant that may be most appropriate (at least in terms of preserving readability). For sure, I'd say that its result looks a lot better than what's produced by `\mathclap`.

Comment: Yep, probably `\smashoperator[r]{..} \quad` is what I would do, or not write it in the subscript at all.